Error message when saving file
When saving a file I get this error message:

unable to pack file,source
path'/users/JL/desktop/floor_tiles_02.blend/textures/floor_tiles_02_disp.png'
not found.

It's a texture I toyed with but did not use and I subsequently deleted the Blender file from my desktop.
How can I tell Blender it's no longer there and stop looking for it.
I' using Blender 3.4.0

Try saving your blend file with File > External Data > Automatically Pack Resources unchecked. Then reload the file and try again with the option checked. If that doesn't work you may have marked the texture with a Fake User so that it isn't automatically deleted when the file is saved.
